# SSIS FTP Connection Manager - Two servers different result?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ftp

I have the same SSIS package ran through MS VISUAL Studio 2008 on two different servers, one of the servers allows the FTP connection through and the other does not.

The package has a password encryption so it stores the FTP password.

I can connect using CMD/FTP.exe and have the same treacert results from the two servers to the FTP IP address; this problem seesm to me MS VISUAL STudio / MSSQL alone.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Positive it's the same package? Could it be that a virus scanner is blocking the automated connection but allows the manual execution?

Comment: It can be firewall that blocking connection from SSIS package execution

Comment: 01/09/2014 10:57:02 Blocked by port blocking rule  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe Common Maximum Protection:Prevent FTP communication You were correct, thank you